# translate unsigned char c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, translate

can i get help to translate this c++ code to c# ?

```
auto tmp2 = new unsigned char[tmp1 + 1];
auto tmp3 = (DWORD)tmp2;
std::cout << "tmp3: " << std::hex << tmp3 << std::endl;
```

tmp1 value is 0xBC3000, tmp3 is 0x1276040

this is what i currently have :

```
var tmp2 = new byte[tmp1 + 1];
//tmp3 ???
MessageBox.Show("tmp3 : " + tmp3.ToString());
```

Comment: You want the address of a 32 bit address (`tmp2`) printed in a `MessageBox`, is that it? Do you have a 32 bit computer? What made you write `auto tmp3 = (DWORD)tmp2;` in the first place? That assumes 32 bit pointers (indirectly).

Comment: yes (tmp3.ToString("X8"))

Comment: i have a 64 bit computer but process is 32 bit

Comment: `C++`: I'd still recommend using `std::uintptr_t` when converting a pointer to an integer. It's made for that purpose: `auto tmp3 = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(tmp2);`.

`C#`: Are you sure `new` returns an actual address that you can print out like that?

Comment: No, you would have to pin it, first. References are moveable. A .NET implementation could use references as a level of indirection to a pointer. .NET Framework doesn't and I'm pretty sure .NET Core doesn't, either, but it's an implementation detail and some implementation might choose to do it. You can't reliably treat a reference as a pointer.

Comment: @user34224 What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? I have a feeling this is one of those common cases where translating code from one language to another does not make sense.

Comment: my problem is that i need tmp3 in my program

Comment: That makes this an XY problem. If it's about interop, frame the question as such. If you're translating a larger piece of code, translate it *semantically*, not line for line.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: It's kind of possible, but you really shouldn't.

C++ uses pointers extensively while C# avoids them as much as possible in user code.  While it is possible to work with pointers it is frowned on when doing most things except interop.  Even then it's more common to use .NET marshalling to abstract the actual pointers.

As has been mentioned in the various comments on the question, C#'s reference types can in principle be moved at any time.  In practice this doesn't happen but it is permissible and there are no guarantees that it won't happen in future.

To make things worse, strings are invariant.  Rather than allocating a buffer and filling it with characters as you do in C++ you have a string reference that changes whenever you change its contents.  Even if you could get the address of one string instance that address would be invalidated when you change the string.  You can use `StringBuilder` instead, but the address of the internal array almost always changes when it is resized.

> my problem is that i need tmp3 in my program

This seems to be the core of the problem.  While you *think* that you need `tmp3` in your program you probably don't.  It all depends on what is being done with it.  Without more information on what you're doing with it we can't do a lot to help.

So... *why* do you need to use `tmp3` in your program?

Comment: i need tmp3 because i need to substract it (auto tmp4 = tmp0 - tmp3;)

Comment: @user34224 Oh god, no.  Pointer arithmetic is a definite **no** in C#, for all of the reasons previously mentioned.  *Why* do you need to subtract these things?  What's the purpose?

Comment: @user34224 Yes.  Even with unsafe code there's no guarantee that unpinned items will stay in the same location.  Find another way to do it.